# How to shuffle tensorflow dataset without buffer?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I meet problem when I try to shuffle the `ds` from the code below:

```
#ds_1 length=20000, ds_2 length=2000
ds_1 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds1, label_ds1))
ds_2 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds2, label_ds2))  #labels in label_ds2 are all the same
ds = ds_1.concatenate(ds_2)
```

Using `ds.shuffle(buffer_size)` with a large buffer size could accomplish this task but it takes large RAM at the same time. The `ds.shuffle()` would always shuffle the `ds` when `ds` is called which is not needed for me. I just want to shuffle ds once and save RAM. Thanks for helps in advance.